# xmonad submap not working

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm new to xmonad and haskell. I try to create a xmonad config on my own, this is the current state: https://gist.github.com/sbechtel/7900440

My problem is the submap on line 45 for different search prompts. It compiles without problems but doesn't do anything. I belief it was working but now it isn't working anymore so my guess is some kind of side effect because I didn't change anything on that line?

Kind regards,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct on first sight to me. Beware though that there is no prompt for the search engine selection. To test it, you have to to press mod1 + s, then g for example. Only then google pops up.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am sorry for this. I thought "the code is correct, it is a usage error" would be an answer. I had exactly the same struggle as Sebastian and my problem was myself, not the code.

Plus I can't comment on the questions yet as I'm new. Is it better to not help at all then? (Serious question for etiquette here, not ment sarcastic).
Sorry for OT btw @ Sebastian